# Unhide/Show column using Google Sheet API

Tags: google-sheets-api

I found the Google Sheet Java API to hide columns, but I couldn't find any API to unhide/show a hidden column. The only way I could figure out till now is using Apps Script. Can you please help with the corresponding Java API?

Comment: Does setting property mentioned in the following answer to FALSE solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42451662/10704949

Comment: No that doesn't, I have tried that. But didn't work

Comment: Check out the answer [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request), seems to be what you're after.